# I couldn't make loop to check numbers of Sudoku game

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, sudoku

Hey I'm trying to code a sudoku game in java and I facing 2 problems

1. the loop doesn't work but it was when I use an int array
2. when I rebate a number in row or column or square it put it at the first time 
   which should not and in the second time it works good but the loop stop 
    and this is my code

   ```
   import java.util.*;
       public class Solution {
           public static boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board) {   
               short[] rows = new short[9];
               short[] cols = new short[9];
               short[] squares = new short[9];
               for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
                   for(int col = 0; col < board[0].length; col++) {
                       if(board[row][col] == '0') continue;
                       short value = (short) (1 << (board[row][col] - '1'));
                       if((value & rows[row]) > 0) return false;
                       if((value & cols[col]) > 0) return false;
                       if((value & squares[3*(row/3) + col/3]) > 0) return false;
                       rows[row] |= value;
                       cols[col] |= value;
                       squares[3*(row/3) + col/3] |= value;
                   }
               }
               return true;
           }
           public static void main(String[] args) {
               Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
               char [][] board = new char[][] {
                       { '1', '2', '3', '4', '9', '7', '8', '6', '5' },
                       { '4', '5', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
                       { '6', '7', '8', '0', '0', '0', '0','0', '0' },
                       { '3', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0' }, 
                       { '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' },
                       { '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0' }, 
                       { '8', '0', '0', '0','0', '0', '0', '0', '0' }, 
                       { '7', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' },
                       { '5', '0', '0', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' } 
                       };
               int rows, column = 0;
               char Ch1;
               String seat;
               int taken = 0 ;
               do {
                   for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                       for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                           System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
                       }
                       System.out.println();
                   }
                   seat = kb.next();
                   rows = Integer.parseInt(seat.substring(0,1)) ; 
                   column =Integer.parseInt(seat.substring(1,2)) ; 
                   Ch1 = seat.charAt(2);
                   if (board[rows-1][column-1] != '0' ) {
                       System.out.println("is full");
                       continue;
                   }
                   if (isValidSudoku(board) == false) {
                       System.out.println(isValidSudoku(board));
                       continue;
                   }
                   board[rows - 1][column-1] = Ch1 ;
                   taken++;
               } while (taken == 57);
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify your question ans stick to one question per post. "the loop doesn't work but it was when I use an int array" What "doesn't work" mean ? How do you know that it does not work ?  Is it still a problem or not ? Tell us what is the expected output and what do you get.

Comment: After the first loop `taken` equals 1 , so `taken == 57` is false and the loop stops.

Comment: @c0der sorry about that, I use do while I need it to fill all blank values before I go out of the loop and the blank values are 57